# Probability of finding 5-nucleotide long sequence in random sequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics

DNA code is composed of a sequence of four nucleotides: adenine (A), cytosine (C), guanine (G) and thymine (T). We assume (for simplicity) that ()=()=()=()=0.25

**My question is:** I have a random DNA chain of length M=14, where position 1 is always a C. The question is now, what is the probability of finding the sequence 'CTAGG' (m=5) within the chain?
The sequence can't overlap with itself.

Comment: When you ask a question very similar to a previous one, it makes sense to link to the previous one so people can build on the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454913

Comment: As you saw in my answer to the previous question, this sort of problem can be solved either with a relatively simple calculation to get a very good approximation, or with a more complicated calculation to get the exact value. It would help if you indicate which of these (or perhaps both) you're interested in.

Comment: I'm interested in both the simple calculation and the more complicated one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the previous question, you get a very good approximation of the probability of occurrence from the expected number of occurrences. We have a special chance of $4^{-4}=2^{-8}$ of getting `CTAGG` in the first position because of the fixed `C`, and then we have probability $4^{-5}=2^{-10}$ to get an occurrence in each of the remaining $14-5+1-1=9$ slots, for a total expected number of $2^{-8}+9\cdot2^{-10}=13\cdot2^{-10}$.

To get the exact probability, we are again in the fortunate situation that at most two occurrences are possible, so we don't have to do a full [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) calculation and can just subtract out the double occurrences.

If the first occurrence uses the initial `C`, then the probability for it is $4^{-4}$, the probability for the second one is $4^{-5}$, and there are $14-2\cdot5+1=5$ possible positions for it, so the probability for this is  $5\cdot2^{-18}$.

If the first occurrence doesn't use the initial `C`, then the probability for each occurrence is $4^{-5}$, and we can choose their positions in $\binom{13-2\cdot5+2}{2}=\binom{5}2=10$ ways, so the probability for this is $10\cdot2^{-20}=5\cdot2^{-19}$.

Thus, the probability for at least one occurrence is

$$
\frac{13}{2^{10}}-\frac5{2^{18}}-\frac5{2^{19}}=\frac{13}{2^{10}}-\frac{15}{2^{19}}\approx 0.0127\;.
$$

Since this differs from the answer provided by Jaroslaw Matlak, I wrote [some code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/8fb2ee97cf626a2741f4c6080f385810) to check it.

Comment: I don't understand why it's (2*5) in: 14−2⋅5+1=5? And also what happens exactly when you use $\binom{13-2+5+2}{2}$ when calculating the positions when the initial 'C' is not used?

Comment: @Amila: If the initial `C` is being used, we have to include that, so we start with $14$; if it isn't, we don't, so we start with $13$. Then we have to subtract the $2\cdot5$ bases that the two occurrences take up to get the number of remaining bases. And then we have to choose positions for the occurrences among these remaining bases. If we have $m$ remaining bases and $k$ occurrences to position among them, that's $k$ positions out of a total of $m+k$ objects, so $\binom{m+k}k$ possibilities. In the first case $m=14-2\cdot5$ and $k=1$; in the second case $m=13-2\cdot5$ and $k=2$.

Comment: I'm a little confused of what is calculated before the double occurrences? What does $\frac{13}{2^{10}}$ really correspond to?

Comment: @Amila: It's the expected number of occurrences, as in my answer to you previous question. If the number of occurrences were always either $0$ or $1$, this would be equal to the probability of having at least one occurrence. Since there are rare cases of chains with two occurrences, the expected number of occurrences is very slightly greater than the probability of occurrence, and we have to subtract from it the probability of a double occurrence to get the probability of at least one occurrence.

Comment: @Amila: If $p_k$ is the probability for $k$ occurrences, the expected number of occurrences is $\sum_kp_kk$. Here we never have more than two occurrences, and only very rarely two, and hence the expected number of occurrences is $\sum_kp_kk=p_0\cdot0+p_1\cdot1+p_2\cdot2=p_1+2p_2\approx p_1+p_2$, and this latter sum, $p_1+p_2$, is the probability of at least one occurrence that we're looking for, so we can substract $p_2$ from the expected number of occurrences $p_1+2p_2$ to get it.

Comment: What happens to the probability if the random nucleotide sequence is 13 and the gene we wan't to find is 5 nucleotides long? I have tried calculating it based on the calculations from your previous answer to my question, but I can't get it right?

Comment: @Amila Why don't you show me your calculations and I'll tell you what's wrong?

Comment: The probability for the 'CCTAG' motif to occur at any given position in the randomized chain is: $4^{-m}=4^{-5}=2^{-10}$ The number of slots in which it might occur is: $M-m+1=13-5+1=9$ slots
Thus the occurrences of the CTAGG motif in the chain is: $9 \cdot 2^{-10}$
The 'CTAGG' sequence cannot occur more than twice, thus the probability for it to occur twice is subtracted. Probability that it occurs twice: $\binom{13+5*2-2}{2}3=10 $ possible positions thus Probability: $10*4^{-13}$. The occurrencce of 'CTAGG' in the randomized part is: $\frac{9}{2^{10}}-\frac{10}{4^{13}}=0.00879$

Comment: @Amila: That's mostly right, except for the factor $4^{-13}$. This should be $4^{-10}$, which you can get either by calculating the probability for the two chunks of length $5$ to both contain `CTAGG`, or by counting the number of possibilities for the $3$ remaining base pairs, $4^{-3}$, and dividing by the number of possibilities for the entire chain without conditions, $4^{-13}$. (Also, you have a typo in the binomial coefficient; the upper index is $13-5\cdot2+2$, not the other way around as you have it; but the value $10$ that you have for it is correct.)

Comment: If I do that, then I get the occurrence to be: $\frac{9}{2^{10}}-\frac{10}{2^{-20}}=0.0088$ ?

Comment: @Amila: That looks good to me (though again you have a typo in the denominator; it should be $2^{20}$). Is that not the answer that you're expecting? (You write "I get the occurrence to be" -- I assume you mean you get the probability of (at least one) occurrence to be that?)

Comment: Sorry for the typos.. Yes, it's because the answer should be approx. 0.0029

Comment: @Amila: Who says so? Can you link to the source?

Comment: It's the answer found using R-code to generate all possible 13-mers and using the grep command to get how many 'CTAGG' occur. This gives 196548 out of 67108864, which is 0.00127. I don't have a link to the source.

Comment: @Amila: No, it's $0.0029$, as you wrote above. I don't know where this discrepancy could come from, and I have no way of finding out without the code and/or the file. Perhaps you could upload either of them? E.g. you could upload the R code to [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: My answer was correct for that situation, I found out that the other result was for the situation where I have the chain: 'CNNNNNNNNNNNNN' and the gene 'CCTAGG'. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Calculations for The situation I have is: CNNNNNNNNNNNNN, where the initial C i fixed and N is a random nucleotide. I want to find the probability of 'CCTAGG' occurring in the chain. My procedure (following your previous answer): Take the initial C into account, special case: $4^{-5}$, and for the rest $4^{-6}*(14-6+1-1)=8*2^{-12}$. Total expected no.: $2^{-10}$+8*2^{-12}=8*2^{-22}$. Situation where we have double occurrence: (1) initial C accounted: $4^{-5}+(14-2*6+1)*$4^{-6}=3*2^{-22}$. (2) wo. initial C: $\binom{13-2*6-2}{2}=3$. calculated prob: $1.01*10^{-6}$ What goes wrong?

Comment: @Amila: $2^{-10}+8\cdot2^{-12}$ isn't $8\cdot2^{-22}$, that would be $2^{-10}\cdot8\cdot2^{-12}$. If you want my honest advice: I think the most effective thing you could do to improve your work would be to try to be more careful; almost everything you write contains a sloppy mistake.